# How can I debug vue.js style is not taking effect?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I need to these 2 styles to run

```
<style scoped>
>>> .description {
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    color: red;
}

>>> li a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
</style>
```

---

Please see my codes

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-container fluid>
            <!-- Dialoge -->

            <v-dialog v-model="deleteStatus" width="500px" class="d-flex justify-center">
                <v-card style="padding: 30px">
                    <v-card-title class="red--text text--lighten-1 d-flex justify-center"> Delete {{ name.replace('-', ' ').replace('s', '') }} </v-card-title>
                    <v-card-text class="text-center"
                        >Are you sure you want to delete <strong>{{ item.name }} </strong> ?</v-card-text
                    >
                    <v-card-actions class="d-flex justify-center">
                        <v-btn small outlined color="darken-3 white--text" @click="deleteStatus = false" class="mx-2">No</v-btn>
                        <v-btn small outlined @click="deleteConfirm()" class="mx-2 red--text">Yes</v-btn>
                    </v-card-actions>
                </v-card>
            </v-dialog>

            <!-- Dialoge -->

            <v-row class="pa-5">
                <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4" lg="4" xl="3">
                    <v-text-field dense outlined v-model="search" append-icon="mdi-magnify" :label="`Search`" single-line hide-details></v-text-field>
                </v-col>

                <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4" lg="2" xl="1" v-if="name == 'campaigns'">
                    <v-select dense outlined :items="statuses" label="Status" v-model="status" v-on:input="sortBy()"></v-select>
                </v-col>

                <v-col cols="12">
                    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items" :search="search">
                        <template v-slot:item.name="{ item }">
                            <router-link :to="`/${name}/${item.id}`"> {{ item.name }}</router-link>
                        </template>

                        <template v-slot:item.priority="{ item }">
                            {{ item.priority }}
                        </template>

                        <template v-slot:item.tag="{ item }">
                            <v-chip small outlined class="ma-2" v-for="tag in item.tag"> {{ tag }} </v-chip>
                        </template>

                        <template v-slot:item.description="{ item }" class="description" style="overflow-wrap: normal">
                            {{ item.description }}
                        </template>

                        <template v-slot:item.id="{ item }">
                            <router-link :to="`/${name}/edit/${item.id}`">
                                <v-btn small outlined class="orange--text"> Edit </v-btn>
                            </router-link>
                            &nbsp;
                            <v-btn small outlined class="red--text" @click="handleDelete(item)"> Delete </v-btn>
                        </template>
                    </v-data-table>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
        </v-container>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Table',
    props: {
        name: String,
        headers: Array,
        items: Array
    },
    data() {
        return {
            search: '',
            status: '',
            statuses: ['Active', 'Disabled'],
            deleteStatus: false,
            item: {}
        }
    },
    methods: {
        sortBy() {
            console.log(this.status)
            this.$emit('sortBy', this.status)
        },
        deleteConfirm() {
            console.log(this.item)
            this.$emit('deleteConfirm', this.item)
            this.deleteStatus = false
        },
        handleDelete(item) {
            this.item = item
            this.deleteStatus = true
        }
    },
    mounted() {}
}
</script>
<style scoped>
>>> .description {
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    color: red;
}

>>> li a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
</style>
```

---

I tried to inspect I see

[image]

Comment: How it looks in HTML when you serve the code in browser? Maybe you can temporarly add some class to the wrapper and check if code is working without `>>>`?

Comment: I tried to inspect, I see `class` ... no name nothing !

Comment: Piercing selector `>>>` is deprecated. The replacement is `:deep(.child)`, but a better solution would be to use CSS variables. If you have a repo and you need more specific help, consider importing it into a codesandbox.io so I could look at your relevant dependencies. What you posted here is not enough to repro.

Comment: Also, `class` and `style` attributes on a slot template won't work. Use a wrapper around the slot's content if you have to.

Answer (score 1):

`<template>` are not rendered in vue@2, so when you apply a class to a `<template>` it's not rendered at all. The empty class attribute which you see in HTML most probably comes from the `<router-link>` element. I suspect the `.description` class for the element is related to "urgent" text content inside.
So you can either replace:

```html
<template v-slot:item.description="{ item }" class="description" style="overflow-wrap: normal">
  {{ item.description }}
</template>
```

with code like below (or any other html element like `span` or `p`):

```html
<div v-slot:item.description="{ item }" class="description" style="overflow-wrap: normal">
  {{ item.description }}
</div>
```

Or if you want to have `.description` class on this `<a>` tag, then apply `.description` to a `router-link`.